# How to filter data and apply specific tags in R

Tags: r

I am filtering lowspenders from the master data file called "newdata" as below.

```
lowspenders = filter(newdata, Monetary >= 0 & Monetary <=91)
```

How do I:

1. Create an additional column in R called "Segment"
2. Name in Segment all of the entries of filter(newdata, Monetary >= 0 & Monetary <=91) with lowspender?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. What is Segment? How do you want to name them? Can you give a reproducible example with expected output?

Comment: `newdata$Segment[newdata$Monetary >= 0 & newdata$Monetary <=91] <- "lowspenders"` - in base R.  However there are other ways

Answer (score 0):

I think the `dplyr` verb you are looking for is [`mutate`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html).  Tie that in with an `if_else`, and you get:

```
mutate(newdata, Segment = if_else(Monetary >= 0 & Monetary < 91, "lowspender", "not lowspender")
```